# Repeated SSL_connect in C causes SIGSEGV

Tags: c, openssl, malloc

I have the following code, and I am getting SIGSEGV on the line:

```
if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL )
```

The fault Im getting is:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffffe5a41e0 in __GI___libc_malloc (bytes=104) at malloc.c:2926
2926    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
```

The program basically is designed to take loads of data and push it into firebase.

The first one element, is to check if we are registered, the next bit is to actually do the registration.

Cutting the program back to basics, we have the following opening gambit:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int iRegistered = checkRegistered();
    int result = registerCar();
}
```

If we swap those two lines, so we register before we check the registration, then we don't get a SIGSEGV.

Here's the checkRegistration function:

```
int checkRegistered() {
    int firebaseRegistered = 0;

    char *carId;
    carId = (char *) malloc(256);

    strcpy(carId, "aabbccddeeffgg" );

    char *payload;
    payload = (char *) malloc(1024);
    sprintf(payload, "{ \"carid\": \"%s\" }", carId);

    char *response;
    response = (char *) malloc(1024);

    int result = firebase("isCarRegistered", payload, &response);

    if (result == 0) {
        // Process JSON Response
        cJSON *json = cJSON_Parse(response);

        if (json == NULL) {
            //
        } else {
            cJSON *json_registered = NULL;
            json_registered = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(json, "registered");
            firebaseRegistered = json_registered->valueint;
        }
    }
    free(response);
    free(payload);
    free(carId);
    return firebaseRegistered;
}
```

And the registerCar function.

They're basically mostly the same format - construct a message, send it to firebase, process the JSON response. We use cJSON to decompile the data returned from Firebase, though we could potentially use it to also compile. But one thing at a time.

You'll see a number of free() statements - I've been trying to work out how best to complete this - ie, generate a char* locally, pass by reference ** to a function, let the function perform the malloc/realloc based on the sizes it can calculate and then we can free it from the calling code once we have dealth with the data. Though I also get a SIGSEGV from that as well.

```
int registerCar() {
    int iResponse = 0;

    char *carId;
    carId = (char *) malloc(256);

    char *authCode;
    authCode = (char *) malloc(12);

    char *payload;
    payload = (char *) malloc(1024);
    sprintf(payload, "{ }");

    char *response;
    response = (char *) malloc(1024);

    int result = firebase("registerCar", payload, &response);
    if (result == 0) {
        // Process JSON Response
        cJSON *json = cJSON_Parse(response);

        if (json == NULL) {
            //
        } else {
            cJSON *json_auth = NULL;
            cJSON *json_car = NULL;

            json_auth = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(json, "authcode");
            json_car = cJSON_GetObjectItemCaseSensitive(json, "carid");
            iResponse = 1;
        }
    }
    free(response);
    free(payload);
    return iResponse;
}
```

Here's the firebase routine, it takes a function, a payload and generates a response. Interestingly here, char *firebaseLocal and char*firebaseMessage is not always null before the initial malloc.

```
int firebase(char *firebaseFunction, char *firebasePayload, char **firebaseResponse) {
    char buf[1024];
    char *firebaseLocal;
    char *firebaseMessage;
    firebaseMessage = (char *) malloc(1024);

    SSL_CTX *ctx;
    int server;
    SSL *ssl;

    int bytes;

    ctx = InitCTX();
    server = OpenConnection(HOST, atoi(PORT));
    ssl = SSL_new(ctx);      /* create new SSL connection state */
    SSL_set_fd(ssl, server);    /* attach the socket descriptor */
    if ( SSL_connect(ssl) == FAIL )   /* perform the connection */
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    else {
        ShowCerts(ssl);        /* get any certs */

        char *firebasePost;
        generatePostMessage(firebaseFunction, firebasePayload, &firebasePost);
        SSL_write(ssl, firebasePost, strlen(firebasePost));

        bytes = SSL_read(ssl, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* get reply & decrypt */
        buf[bytes] = 0;
        //SSL_free(ssl);        /* release connection state */

        strcpy(firebaseMessage, buf);
        firebaseLocal = strstr(firebaseMessage, "\r\n\r\n");
        if (firebaseLocal != NULL) {
            firebaseLocal +=4;
        }
        strcpy(*firebaseResponse, firebaseLocal);
    }

    free(firebaseMessage);

    close(server);         /* close socket */
    SSL_CTX_free(ctx);        /* release context */
    return 0;
}
```

This is from an implementation I found on secure sockets.

```
int OpenConnection(const char *hostname, int port)
{   int sd;
  struct hostent *host;
  struct sockaddr_in addr;

  if ( (host = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL )
  {
    perror(hostname);
    abort();
  }
  sd = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  bzero(&addr, sizeof(addr));
  addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
  addr.sin_port = htons(port);
  addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long*)(host->h_addr);
  if ( connect(sd, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0 )
  {
    close(sd);
    perror(hostname);
    abort();
  }
  return sd;
}
```

This is from an implementation I found on secure sockets.

```
SSL_CTX* InitCTX(void)
{
  SSL_METHOD *method;
  SSL_CTX *ctx;
  SSL_library_init();

  OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();  /* Load cryptos, et.al. */
  SSL_load_error_strings();   /* Bring in and register error messages */
  method = TLSv1_2_client_method();  /* Create new client-method instance */
  ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);   /* Create new context */
  if ( ctx == NULL )
  {
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    abort();
  }
  return ctx;
}
```

This is from an implementation I found on secure sockets.

```
void ShowCerts(SSL* ssl)
{   X509 *cert;
  char *line;

  cert = SSL_get_peer_certificate(ssl); /* get the server's certificate */
  if ( cert != NULL )
  {
    printf("Server certificates:\n");
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Subject: %s\n", line);
    free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
    line = X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), 0, 0);
    printf("Issuer: %s\n", line);
    free(line);       /* free the malloc'ed string */
    X509_free(cert);     /* free the malloc'ed certificate copy */
  }
  else
    printf("Info: No client certificates configured.\n");
}
```

This is something that I wrote to generate a post message from message

```
void generatePostMessage(char *firebaseFunction, char *firebaseMessage, char **response) {
    int intPayloadSize = strlen(firebaseMessage);
    char *charPayloadSize;
    charPayloadSize = (char *) malloc(8);
    sprintf(charPayloadSize, "%d", intPayloadSize);

    char *postmessage = "POST /%s HTTP/1.1\r\n"
                         "Host: us-central1-carconnect-e763e.cloudfunctions.net\r\n"
                         "User-Agent: USER_AGENT\r\n"
                         "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
                         "Accept: text/plain\r\n"
                         "Content-Length: %d\r\n\r\n"
                         "%s";

    // Allocate size of postmessage less the inserts, plus the payload size, plus the payload size digits, plus null
    int responseLength = (strlen(postmessage) - 4) + intPayloadSize + strlen(charPayloadSize)+1;
    // Round up Four Bytes.
    int responseIncrease = responseLength % 4;
    if (responseIncrease > 0) {
        responseLength += (4 - responseIncrease);
    }
    *response = (char *) malloc(responseLength);
    sprintf(*response, postmessage, firebaseFunction, intPayloadSize, firebaseMessage);
}
```

As advised, whether the registration or registration check is called first, the first call works fine.

If I perform the registration before the check, then both commands work fine. Further testing also does confirm the problem is the registration check. I can perform registration several times without fail. The registration check and any follow up calls fail completely at the SSL_connect line. I don't know why.

The SSL_free command in the firebase connection always fails. I also get a SIGSEGV if I try to free(firebasePost) after the SSL_Write - which suggests I cannot free a pointer that has been passed by reference and mallocced in a function.

Part of me wonders whether any of this is caused by the fact Im debugging on Windows. I've always had problems with malloc() on Windows just not working the way I would expect.

Comment: Whenever you see a crash inside the guts of `malloc`, your first suspicion should be that something wrote past the end of a `malloc` block and corrupted the heap.  The best available tool for finding the root cause of the problem is `valgrind`.  You say you're on Windows, but the name `__GI___libc_malloc` suggests Linux instead, which is good, because `valgrind` doesn't work on Windows last I heard.  Anyway, run the program under `valgrind`, fix the _very first_ thing it complains about, repeat until no more errors. If you don't understand the errors you get, edit them into this question.

Comment: Do not be surprised when `valgrind` tells you that the problem is in code you didn't even think of looking at.  This is why we make a fuss about seeing _complete programs_ that we can run for ourselves when people ask questions like this.

Comment: I am using Windows and CLion, however I have it hooked into the WIndows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Thanks for the tips on valgrind - I shall have to take a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem, or at least one of them, is in `generatePostMessage`. Not enough buffer is allocated for `response`. `sprintf` will then run off the end of the allocated buffer and cause heap corruption, which manifests itself on next invocation of `malloc`. Try:

```
int responseLength = strlen(firebaseFunction) + (strlen(postmessage) - 4) + intPayloadSize + strlen(charPayloadSize)+1;
```

Comment: Give this person a gold star. I can't believe I missed something so obvious as missing out the length of this particular string. How can I find out what the previous malloc was in future cases as this?

Comment: @Simon What do you mean by "previous malloc"?

Comment: Just what you said. You said that the issue will manifest itself on the next malloc. How do you determine which previous invocation of malloc caused the error? You were pretty quick to find the error.

Comment: Ahh, well that's where valgrind comes in, as somebody suggested in the question comments. I spotted the error from experience, but if you were to debug this, valgrind should tell you that you overran the buffer. BTW it doesn't have to be the next malloc that crashes, if you're "lucky" it could take a while or not even happen (behavior is undefined)